# WebClient call endpoint API twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, webclient

```
@PutMapping()
public void calApi() {
    Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
    requestBody.put("foo", "bar");
    webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/api/v1/endpoint")
        .bodyValue(requestBody)
        .retrieve()
        .toBodilessEntity()
        .block();
}
```

When i call the calApi controller method, the webClient call end point twice. Why the webClient do that or did i do something wrong?